# PHP strtotime bug help fix

Tags: php, strtotime

```
 $end = strtotime('2011-09-01');
 $start = strtotime('today');

 while($start > $end)
 {
echo date('F Y', $start) . "<br>";

$start = strtotime("-1 month", $start);
 }
```

Results:
April 2014
March 2014
March 2014
February 2014
January 2014
December 2013
...etc

Why am I getting March 2014 twice?
Please if anybody could help, thanks.

Comment: Because there isn't a 29th of February this year.... 29th April (today) -1 month = 29th March, 29th March -1 month = 29th February, which is one day after the last day in February, so you get 1st March, 1st March -1 month = 1st February, etc.... you'd see this for yourself if you were echoing the day as well as the month and year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working with `DateTime()`. By starting with the end date I was starting with the first of the month. That made the number of days in each month irrelevant. Then all I had to do was reverse the array of dates to have it meet your desired format.

```
$start    = new DateTime('2011-09-01');
$end      = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$months= array();
foreach ($period as $dt) { 
    $months[] = $dt->format('F Y');
}
$months = array_reverse($months);
echo implode('<br>', $months);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CzcvBC)